# Does convergence in distribution in each coordinate combined with independent coordinates give convergence in distribution to the random vector?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I know that weak convergence in each coordinate does not necessarily give convergence in distribution to the random vector composed of the coordinate weak limits. However, I was wondering if this would be true if we added the condition that the coordinates are independent. That is, let $X_n = (X_n^{(1)}, ..., X_n^{(k)})$ where the $k$ coordinates are independent, and where $X_n^{(l)} \to X^{(l)}$ in distribution for each $1 \le l \le k$. If the random vector $X$ is also made up of independent coordinates, is it true that $X_n \to X = (X^{(1)}, ..., X^{(k)})$ in distribution?

I think that the answer is yes and I tried to prove it using characteristic functions. Let $u \in \mathbb{R}^k$:

$\phi_{X_n}(u) = \mathbb{E}[e^{i \langle u, X_n \rangle}]  = \mathbb{E}[e^{i \sum_{l=1}^{k} u_l X_n^{(l)}}] = \Pi_{l=1}^{k} \mathbb{E}[e^{i u_l X_n^{(l)}}]$ by independence of coordinates $= \Pi_{l=1}^{k} \phi_{X_n^{(l)}}(u_l) \to \Pi_{l=1}^{k} \phi_{X^{(l)}}(u_l) $ by weak convergence in each coordinate

This last expression is precisely $\phi_X(u) = \mathbb{E}[e^{i \langle u, X \rangle}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{i \sum_{l=1}^{k} u_l X^{(l)}}] = \Pi_{l=1}^{k} \mathbb{E}[e^{i u_l X^{(l)}}]$ if the coordinates $X_l$ are independent $= \Pi_{l=1}^{k} \phi_{X^{(l)}}(u_l)$ as desired.

I was hoping that someone could verify my proof, or correct me if the claim is false. If the claim is false, a counterexample would be nice.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: thanks, do I also need the condition that the weak limits $X^l$ are independent, or is this unnecessary?